# javascript bingo game table issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have hit a wall... creating a bingo game and I can see the following issue: When I start the game the table goes from 0 to 9, 10 to 19, 20 to 29 etc.

I need it to go from 1 to 10, 11 to 20, 21 to 30 etc.

I have been staring at it for a while now and cant figure it out.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
div     {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bigNumberDisplay {
            font-size: 10em;
        }

        .numbersTable {
            font-size: 3em;
        }

        table {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        table, tr, td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: solid 1px #999;
        }

        td {
            min-width: 200px;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

        td.selected {
            color: #f00;
            background-color: #A3B86C;
            border: solid 1px #000000;
        }
        #btnGenerate{
            width: 270px;  
            height: 60px;
            color: red;
            background-position: center;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-align: right;
            white-space: normal;

        }

</style>
    <script>
$(function() {
    var bingo = {
        selectedNumbers: [],
        generateRandom: function() {
            var min = 1;
            var max = 89;
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            return random;
        },
        generateNextRandom: function() {
            if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
                alert("Game over!");
                return 0;
            }
            var random = bingo.generateRandom();
            while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
                random = bingo.generateRandom();
            }
            bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
            return random;
        }
    };
    $('td').each(function() {
        var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
        $(this).addClass("cell" + numberString).text(numberString);
    });
    $('#btnGenerate').click(function() {
        var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
        $('.bigNumberDisplay span').text(random);
        $('td.cell' + random).addClass('selected');
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var returnString = 'Are you sure?';
        if (e) {
            e.returnValue = returnString;
        }
        return returnString;
    };
});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
    <div>
        <span>BingoDesk</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
        <span>0</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Hit Spacebar or click below to generate a number!</p>
        <audio id="sound1" src="chewbacca.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
        <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" autofocus value="" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();"/>
    </div>

    <br/>

    <div class="numbersTable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
                <td> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <br/>

    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help! The only thing I am looking for help with is the grid, so instead of it going 0-9 I want it to start at 1 and go to 10. This just calls the numbers, the idea is that players have pre printed cards and as each number is randomly generated they mark them off on their cards. The grid contains the numbers already called but as the cards are in a table format first column is 1-10 second column 11-20 the current table does not accurately represent this. This is a not for profit project,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in how you get the number value:.

Replace:

```
var numberString = parseInt(concatClass, 10).toString();
$(this).addClass("cell" + numberString).text(numberString);
```

With:

```
var number = parseInt(concatClass, 10) + 1;
$(this).addClass("cell" + number ).text(number);
```

Notice the `+ 1`, and that I removed `.toString()` (`toString` isn't necessary).
Also, `var max = 90;`

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  var bingo = {
    selectedNumbers: [],
    generateRandom: function() {
      var min = 1;
      var max = 90;
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      return random;
    },
    generateNextRandom: function() {
      if (bingo.selectedNumbers.length > 88) {
        alert("Game over!");
        return 0;
      }
      var random = bingo.generateRandom();
      while ($.inArray(random, bingo.selectedNumbers) > -1) {
        random = bingo.generateRandom();
      }
      bingo.selectedNumbers.push(random);
      return random;
    }
  };

  $('td').each(function() {
    var concatClass = this.cellIndex + "" + this.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var number = parseInt(concatClass, 10) + 1;
    $(this).addClass("cell" + number).text(number);
  });

  $('#btnGenerate').click(function() {
    var random = bingo.generateNextRandom().toString();
    $('.bigNumberDisplay span').text(random);
    $('td.cell' + random).addClass('selected');
  });

  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var returnString = 'Are you sure?';
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = returnString;
    }
    return returnString;
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

.bigNumberDisplay {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.numbersTable {
  font-size: 1em;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #999;
}

td {
  min-width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

td.selected {
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #A3B86C;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
}

#btnGenerate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
  background-position: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>BingoDesk</span>
  </div>
  <div class="bigNumberDisplay">
    <span>0</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Hit Spacebar or click below to generate a number!</p>
    <audio id="sound1" src="chewbacca.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <input id="btnGenerate" type="button" autofocus value="" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play();" />
  </div>
  <div class="numbersTable">
    <table>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```